# How to have one event prevent another event from firing on form submit in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="validation.js"></script>
    <script>
      function show_warning()
      {
        // If some condition is true, show a warning when the form is being submitted
        if (condition)
        {
          alert("Warning");
        }
      }

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").submit(show_warning);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method=POST>
        ...
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my validation.js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function( event ) {
      if (some_field_is_invalid)
      {
        alert("Error");
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

I want my show_warning to only fire when the form passed validation, and is actually being submitted. Right now, even if validation fails, it still shows the warning.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken (Its been a while I used jquery events handling), hope community will correct me.

TL;DR;
Remove this:

```js
function show_warning()
{
  // If some condition is true, show a warning when the form is being submitted
  if (condition)
  {
    alert("Warning");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(show_warning);
});
```

and update your validation.js like this:

```html
// You can refactor the code to transform if to ternary
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function( event ) {
      if (some_field_is_invalid)
      {
        alert("Error");
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      // Your special condition. Warning will show if form is valid and condition is true, if condition is not true but form is valid then it will submit without warning
      } else if (condition) {
        alert('Warning');
      }
    });
});
```

Explanation:
You are assigning 2 listeners in your code, one in your html and one in validation js, basically you have 2 functions listening to submit and both of them are independend from each other and being fired on submit of the form. But only validation.js is checking the validity of the form and show_warning is not checking the same validity, it has its own different condition (I dont know what condition is that). If you combine both of them in one listener function you will reach what you wanted.

P.S.
I would recommend you to use validation.js as a service so that it would provide you the function or a class that will return boolean based on the form validity and you would be able to use that method/class to first validate and then do what you need after its passed.
small example:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Lets say validation.js provides a function isFormValid(submitEvent): boolean -->
    <!-- You can implement validation anyhow you want -->
    <script src="validation.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").submit(function(event) {
            if (!isFormValid(event)) {
              return event.preventDefault();
            }
            
            // Form is valid do what you need here
            if (condition) {
              alert('Warning');
            }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: I would prefer not to combine both the validation, and the warning into one file because my validation code has nothing to do with my warning code. They are testing 2 different, unrelated things. Most of the pages that use validation.js don't need the warning code. Your second example on the other hand - having the validation code return a boolean I can check, might just be what I need. I'll give that a try. Thanks

Comment: I realize that I'm adding 2 event handlers for the same event, which as far as I know isn't a problem. Is there no way to have the first event handler stop processing of other handlers for the same event?

Comment: Problem is not that you have 2 listeners, problem is that your 2nd listener doesnt depend on first listener, but you want it to be dependant as validation happens on first listener

Comment: So the only way to make one dependent on the other is to have one call the other? There's no way to make one listener stop the browser from executing any other listeners for that event?

Comment: well, if you do some dirty hack maybe it will be possible, but look at the case as a pipeline, if you have 2 processes that should be dependant on each others result, then you must prioritize them and run one after another, but here you just run your function paralelly, of course you can perform form validation in both methods but it doesnt sound clean. Just create 2 functions, and the second function must call first one, and use its result. like in my last code snippet